# Fragment is lost when navigating a link on Windows 10 with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

Windows 10 appears or have an annoying bug related to URLs with fragments (aka hashes or anchors). To see this:

- set your default browser to Chrome (it doesn't happen with IE/Edge)
- hit Win-R to get the Run menu
- Paste `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#References` and hit enter

**Result**: Chrome goes to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier`. Note the missing `#References` fragment, causing it to go to the top of the page.

The same thing happens when navigating the same link from Outlook, which in practice is the scenario that causes more pains.

**Questions**:

- are others indeed seeing the same issue?
- are there any known workarounds to avoid it? I'm not including "switching browser" as a workaround :)

Comment: I will add that all links I have come across outside of Chrome seem to have this behavior (including shortcuts and links in Outlook)

Comment: @MatthewK yes, I think it's anything that goes through ShellExecute, which is probably most link navigation scenarios.

Comment: Something sure changed in Win10 to make it not work, but other browsers seem to handle it fine. So the most likely course of action would be... file a bug report on Chrome, and wait for a Chrome update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Issue [157056](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157056) on the chromium project (which was reported in 2012) suggests others have had this problem with previous versions of Windows. The issue has not yet been "verified" by the chromium team. I also have this problem.

I found that chrome itself can still open a URL with a fragment:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>"
chrome.exe 127.0.0.1/test.html#foobar
```

I determined when Run is being used, a "delegate_execute.exe" was running. By the point chrome.exe is called, the URL fragment was dropped.

That executable is signed by Google and exists on my machine at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\44.0.2403.155
```

**Workaround**

2) I'm not sure what the exe does and am using the following workaround:

Open Regedit and browse to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command
```

Delete or rename the `DelegateExecute` Key

I didn't have to restart anything after making the change to get Outlook links and Run links to work.

Comment: Workaround worked like a charm. Didn't even have to restart Chrome. Thanks much!

Comment: I've found I have to reapply this workaround after any auto-update of Chrome.

Comment: It looks like the Chromium bug that tracks the actual work is https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516349. Seems they're aiming for Chrome 46 to fix is I understand correctly.